# How to Send an Email on Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, email, oracle-apex

I'm building a little application using Oracle Application Express Online. I'd like to send automatically email when an user inserts into the database a row.
I created an Item, called Email, in which I put the address of the user of the application:

```
Select User.Email from Users wher Users.Username=:APP_USER
```

Query works, because in the application I see right email.
Then I create a process in the way you see in the screen I'll post here. But nothing happens. Can you help me, please?

As you see, in the centre of the photo there are 2 items: one has to go into the database to store a new row, the second one is the email that is in the process. But, as I said early, nothing happens.

[image: As you see, in the centre of the photo there are 2 items: one has to go into the database to store a new row, the second one is the email that is in the process. But, as I said early, nothing happens.]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: First, a minor thing - I don't know if a bind variable (:EMAIL) will work in that field; you might need a substitution variable (&EMAIL.) instead.

Comment: Second, you have to do some configuration setup to be able to send email. You don't say which version of ApEx you're using, but see here for example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E71588_01/AEAPI/Configuring-Oracle-Application-Express-to-Send-Email.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My only problem is when I put a "dynamic variable, such as :EMAIL or &EMAIL. I don't think that it's a configuration problem, because if I put two static email (such as my email and yours), Apex sends it. I'm using Apex online (this: https://apex.oracle.com/en/ ), don't know what version is, sorry. Do you think that everything is correct in the process?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on any attribute in APEX, and click the "Help" tab, you get some very useful information - in this case, that the field expects a substitution syntax for this scenario.

> **To**
>
> Enter the email recipients by specifying one or more email addresses.
>   For multiple email addresses, use a comma-separated list. Use
>   substitution syntax if you want to use a dynamic value.
>
> **Examples**
>
> ```
> john.doe@test.com, jane.doe@test.com
> John Doe <john.doe@test.com>, Jane Doe <jane.doe@test.com>
> &P6_TO.
> ```